# How to select the "locals" min and max out of a list in a panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm struggling to figure out how to do the following:
I've a dataframe that looks like this (it's a little more complicated, this is but an example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['id1','id2'], 'coverage' : ['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50','1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110']})
```

And I want to generate a new key that only holds the min-max of every segment, basically it should look like this:

```
    id          coverage
0  id1  1 11 13 20 40 50 
1  id2  1 10 100 110
```

It's a simple problem but I can't come up with any solutions, I know that map(lambda x:) could work...
Thanks!

Comment: It's not obviously simple given your data structure :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, split those strings and then explode into a large Series, keeping the index as your `'id'` column. Then we take the difference between successive rows within each group and check where it's not equal to `1`.

Slice the exploded Series by this mask and it shifted to get the start and end points, then groupby and `agg(list)` (or `' '.join`) to get your output.

```
# To numeric so values become numbers.
s = pd.to_numeric(df.set_index('id')['coverage'].str.split().explode())

m = s.groupby(level=0).diff().ne(1)
result = s[m | m.shift(-1).fillna(True)].groupby(level=0).agg(list)

id
id1    [1, 11, 13, 20, 40, 50]
id2          [1, 10, 100, 110]
Name: coverage, dtype: object
```

Comment: This answer seems to be correct, even though there's a problem when a sequence has a number that's part of another sequence, ie: [1 [..] 10, 2 [...] 16] delivers  [1,10, 2, 16], when the expected result should be [1, 16].  Nonetheless, thanks!! OOpoopps nevermind it works flawlessly! Thanks!!!

Comment: @JuanMacD hmmm in that case I believe you could sort the Series before and then deal with duplicates (maybe drop them) then apply the above to get what you'd want.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
# split the values and convert to integers
s = df['coverage'].str.split().explode().astype(int)

# continuous blocks
blocks = s.diff().ne(1).groupby(level=0).cumsum()

s['coverage'] = (s.groupby([s.index, blocks])
  .agg(['min','max'])
  .astype(str).agg(' '.join, axis=1)
  .groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
)
```